# Prove that $f(x)=x+g(x)$ is open map, where $g$ is Lipschitz continuous

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Problem:

> Let $g:U\to\Bbb{R}^n$ be a function defined on an open subset $U$ in $\Bbb{R}^n$ s.t. $\forall x,y \in U$, $|g(x)-g(y)|\leq \alpha|x-y|$, where $\alpha$ is a constant in $(0,1)$. Define $f(x) = x+g(x)$, prove that $f(U)$ is open.

Approach:

I have shown that $(1-\alpha)|x-y|\leq|f(x)-f(y)|\leq (1+\alpha)|x-y|$ and $f$ is injective. And I guess that : for any $y_0\in f(u)$, take a $x_0\in U$ and a $\epsilon>0$ s.t. $f(x_0)=y_0$ and $B_{\epsilon}(x_0)\subseteq U$. Then $B_{\epsilon(1-\alpha)}(y_0)\subseteq f(U)$. But I don't know how to prove it, and I have no other approach.

Please give me some hints, thank you.

Comment: If you can show that $f$ is surjective, you can easily see that $f^{-1}$ is also Lipschitz continuous and hence $f$ is a homeomorphism.

Comment: @DanielFischer But in my homework, this is problem part(a) and proving f has an inverse is part(b)...maybe there are some other approaches?

Comment: Use Banach Fixed Point Theorem.

Comment: Sure, there are other approaches. What machinery can you use?

Comment: I have considered Banach fixed point theorem, like for any $y\in f(U)$, consider $2x-y+g(x)$, then the fixed point of this function will be a 'solution' of y.
But I don't know how to choose a suitable complete metric space to apply the fixed point theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint.** WLOG we may assume $0\in U$ and $f(0)=0$. Consider the map
$$\varphi_y:x\mapsto y-g(x)$$
which is a contraction. For sufficiently small $|y|$ it maps $\bar{B}_\epsilon(0)$ into itself, thus we have shown that $f$ is locally invertible(hence an open map) by Fixed Point Theorem. This is just a standard proof for the inverse function theorem. Furthermore, it's not hard to find that $f$ is injective, hence is invertible and is a homeomorphism.